# react-native-share showing black screen at first on share reel to instagram

Tags: react-native, instagram, react-native-share, instagram-reels

i am using react-native-share "^9.2.3" or  "^9.0.2" tried both versions.
I download video from react-native in my cache

```
const shareInsta = async () => {
    const cache = await RNFetchBlob.config({
      fileCache: true,
      appendExt: 'mp4',
    }).fetch('GET', downloading_path_url, {}).then((res) => {

    const destPath = RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + `/video.mp4`;
            await RNFS.copyFile(res.path(), destPath);
            setTimeout(async() => {
                 await Share.shareSingle({
                 social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM,
                 type: "video/*",
                 url: `file://${destPath}`,
                 failOnCancel: false,
               })            
             },1000)
          });
       cache.flush()
    }
```

After downloading video in cache, I pass its path in Share.shareSingle function in url parameter, then it will show me a options to share on instagram chat, story, feed and reel.
When I pressed on reels it will open up the instagram and navigate me to upload reel screen but with a black screen. Its not showing video but when I clicked on next it shows that video is exist but its not playing and showing black screen

Android 10
Android 13